# Unable to create Android Virtual Device. NullPointerException at setDefaultDevices(DeviceDefinitionList.java:153)

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio is `1.5.1`.

In AVD Manager, click `Create Virtual Device` and got a `NullPointerException`.

[image]

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.DeviceDefinitionList.setDefaultDevices(DeviceDefinitionList.java:153)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.DeviceDefinitionList.<init>(DeviceDefinitionList.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.$$$setupUI$$$(ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.<init>(ChooseDeviceDefinitionStep.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdConfigurationPath.init(AvdConfigurationPath.java:34)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:242)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdEditWizard.init(AvdEditWizard.java:84)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.CreateAvdAction.actionPerformed(CreateAvdAction.java:40)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

I removed `/User/.android` folder and reinstalled Android Studio, but still the same.

Here's my setting about SDK.

[image]

I also tried **Invalidate Caches / Restart**.

***UPDATE**

If I launch SDK Manager **standalone** and go to menu : Tools > Manage AVDs. I succeed to create and start device there.

[image]

And now this error is constantly popping up. Note that I didn't installed about "wear" things..

[image]

Comment: having a similar issue in Android studio 3.2.1 and i don't see an option to launch it in standalone mode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722622/android-studio-3-2-1-virtual-device-creation-error

Answer (score 0):

in sdk tools download "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer)" version 6.0.1 you must download that.

then

go to sdk location "...\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" and install "intelhaxm-android.exe"

you should install that for use avd

plus

in sdk platforms download "Intel x86 Atom system Image"

better check them in sdk manager 
[image]

if you need wear emulator you must download wear sdk too

please download "android wear Intel x86 Atom system Image"

Comment: Not working. I would like you know that HAXM was already installed(i didn't remove it) and reinstalled it this time.

Comment: Is there any possible that Android Studio is having trouble with Eclipse? Though I'm not running both at once.

Comment: but you can unistall Eclipse and try again. you dont need Eclipse

Comment: and if you have emulator in Eclipse remove that

Comment: I know. I need Eclipse for another job

Comment: did you check hyper-v or 
intel virtualization?

Comment: Yes.. I don't have any emulator in Eclipse nor Virtual machines. And  I somehow create a device and facing another error : could not load wear device. I updated on the question.

Answer (score -3):

One suggestion: try with Genymotion.
Is better (from all points of view) then AVD. 
Official site: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/