# Android Studio 3.2.1 Virtual device creation error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm on Mac OSX mojave trying to create a virtual device using Android virtual Device Manger But I keep getting the following error:

> @NotNull method
>   com/android/tools/idea/avdmanager/AvdOptionsModel.getCreatedAvd must
>   not return null java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method
>   com/android/tools/idea/avdmanager/AvdOptionsModel.getCreatedAvd must
>   not return null   at
>   com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdOptionsModel.$$$reportNull$$$0(AvdOptionsModel.java)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdOptionsModel.getCreatedAvd(AvdOptionsModel.java:881)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.CreateAvdAction.actionPerformed(CreateAvdAction.java:44)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:759)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Did you get any solution for this because i am also facing same issue..